# Asp.Net Show Default Error Page that works with $ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have a hybrid asp.net web forms/mvc application.  When a 500 error occurs I want to do the following:

1. show a custom *.aspx page if the error occurred on a web form.
2. show a custom mvc view if the error occurred in a controller action that returns a view.
3. show a custom message constructed in javascript if the error occurred in a controller action that is responding to a $ajax request.  **This 3rd item is where I am having problems.**

In all cases I want to log the error exactly once.  I log web forms errors in the global.asax Application_OnError event procedure.  For my mvc controllers I've added this call to the Application_Start event procedure:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
```

and then created a base class that all controllers in the application derive from.  In this base class I log errors in the OnException event procedure. Error logging works fine.

For item 1, the custom *.aspx page, I added this to my web.config, and it successfully redirects all webforms errors to my custom error page:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="MyFolder/MyDefaultErrorPage.aspx"
```

For item 2, the custom mvc view, I found I needed to catch the IIS error in the httpErrors element in my web.config.  This successfully redirects all controller errors to my custom error view:

```
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <clear />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/MyFolder/MyErrorView" responseMode="Redirect"/>
</httpErrors>
```

All of the above works fine, but unfortunately item 2, which intercepts the IIS 500 error, causes all $ajax calls to return to the success: event handler instead of the error: event handler, even when the controller action throws an exception.  For example, I make this call from javascript to a controller action:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/MyFolder/MyControllerAction',
            success: function (data) {
                do_something(data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, ex) {
                show_error_message(XMLHttpRequest, ex); 
            }
```

The problem is that when MyControllerAction throws an exception the "success:" event handler is called, not the "error:" event handler. If I remove the node from my web.config that intercepts the IIS 500 error I hit the desired "error:" event handler in my $ajax call, but it shows the default IIS 500 error page, not my custom error page.

Is there any way to show a custom error page for all of my Controller errors and still have the error: event handler fire when I do a $ajax call from javascript?

Update: If I create a custom class derived from HandleErrorAttribute and use that in GlobalFilters.Filters.Add() I get partway there.  This causes the "error:" event to fire in my javascript $ajax call.  The problem is the XMLHttpRequest.responseText does not contain my custom message (it just says "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.").  If there is any way to pass a custom message to the XMLHttpRequest.responseText that gets returned to the $.ajax call?

```
public class MyCustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()
            && filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            //500 is needed so that $ajax "error:" event handler is hit, instead of "success:"
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new
                {
                    Message = "Custom message will go here"
                }
            };

            //this stops Application_OnError from firing
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ContentResult()
            {
                Content = "<html><body>Custom message will go here</body></html>",
                ContentType = "text/html"
            };
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum it up: when a runtime error occurs on the server, I want to be able to pass a custom error message to the $ajax event handler (I don't want the default IIS error message), and I want the $ajax "error:" function to fire (not the "success:" function).

The custom HandleErrorAttribute outlined in the question above works, but two more changes are needed to override the default IIS error message:

1. Add this line to the first "if" block (the "if" block that handles an ajax error) in the OnException procedure in the custom attribute:

   filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
2. Add this to the httpErrors tag in web.config:

   errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough"

The value for existingResponse can also be "Auto"

My final custom attribute looks like this:

```
public class MyCustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //log the error
        if (filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            //note that Application_Error makes the same call for errors it handles.
            //this method and Application_Error are the only two places in the application where errors are handled.
            MyErrorLogger(filterContext.Exception.GetBaseException());
        }

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()
            && filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            //this is an error from a $ajax call.
            //500 is needed so that $ajax "error:" function is hit, instead of "success:"
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = new 
                {
                    MyCustomMessage="A custom error message",
                    IsException = true
                }
            };

            //this stops Application_OnError from firing
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

            //this stops the web site from using the default IIS 500 error. 
            //in addition must set existingResponse="PassThrough" or "Auto" in web.config httpErrors element.
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //this is an error in a controller method that returns a view
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    {"action", "Error500" },
                    {"controller", "Error" },
                    { "Message", "My custom message here."}
                });
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The custom error message created above is parsed client-side as a JSON object in the "XMLHttpRequest.responseText" parameter of the "error:" function:

```
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, ex) {
    alert(jQuery.parseJSON(XMLHttpRequest.responseText).MyCustomMessage);
        }
```